# How to post file to web api using vb.net

Tags: php, vb.net

I am mean stack and php developer but i am new to vb.net development my employers want me to convert php code to vb.net in which i want to post file contents to api i have written vb.net code to some extent but everytime i try to build it exists with error code 0

Below given is my php code

```
<?php
$target_url = 'http://192.62.254.22/upload_txt.php';
$file_name_with_full_path = realpath("d:/xampp/htdocs/CMT/test_sms.txt");
if (function_exists('curl_file_create')) 
{ 
$cFile = curl_file_create($file_name_with_full_path);
}    
else 
{ 
$cFile = '@' . realpath($file_name_with_full_path);
}    
$post = array('Username' => '03214571413 ','From'=>'8548','Message'=>'ٹیسٹ','Unicode'=>'1','file_contents'=>$cFile,'Password'=>'Aabcd1234');

$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,$target_url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST,1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $post);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, true);
$result=curl_exec ($ch);
curl_close ($ch);
echo $result;
?>
```

And Below Given Is VB.Net

```
Imports System.Collections.Generic
Imports System.IO
Imports System.Net.Http
Imports System.Net.Http.Headers
Public Class Class1
Public Shared Sub Main()
GoPost()
End Sub

Private Shared Sub GoPost()

Dim parameters As Dictionary(Of String, String) = New Dictionary(Of String, String)()
parameters.Add("Username", "03214571413")
parameters.Add("From", "8548")
parameters.Add("Message", "testabc")
parameters.Add("Unicode", "1")
parameters.Add("Password", "Aabcd1234")
Dim client As HttpClient = New HttpClient()
Dim form As MultipartFormDataContent = New MultipartFormDataContent()
Dim content As HttpContent = New StringContent("fileToUpload")
Dim DictionaryItems As HttpContent = New FormUrlEncodedContent(parameters)
form.Add(content, "fileToUpload")
form.Add(DictionaryItems, "medicineOrder")
Dim stream = New FileStream("c:\xampp\test.txt", FileMode.Open)
content = New StreamContent(stream)
content.Headers.ContentDisposition = New ContentDispositionHeaderValue("form-data") With {
    .Name = "fileToUpload",
    .FileName = "test.txt"
}
form.Add(content)
Dim response As HttpResponseMessage = Nothing

Try
    response = (client.PostAsync("http://192.62.254.22/upload_txt.php", form)).Result
Catch ex As Exception
    Console.WriteLine(ex.Message)
End Try

Dim k = response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result
End Sub
End Class
```

Answer (score -1):

If you could give a string example of multipart form that your page expects (from browser) I could probably help you. As from the question I (we?) don't know what is the data that the page expects. It's in that CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS?

I was doing something recently and for this

```
-----------------------------number
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="service[]"
0
-----------------------------number
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="file"; filename="something.png"
Content-Type: image/png
PNG
bytearray
-----------------------------number--
```

I did the following:

```
Dim EncodedContent As New MultipartFormDataContent
EncodedContent.Add(New StringContent("0"), "service[]")
EncodedContent.Add(New ByteArrayContent(ImageBytes), "file", "something.png")
Dim Response As String = New HttpClient().PostAsync("http:...", EncodedContent).Result.Content.ReadAsStringAsync.Result
```

---

I will drop the answer here.